# power point : unable to move or resize object

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I got a issue with a powerpoint slide,
I use powerpoint 2010, the original file was created with a powerpoint 365.

Here the screen capture : 
[image]

I click or right-click on the shape and I can't move or resize (with mouse or input fields) but I can change colors (borders, and inside).

It's not relative to layouts...

what did i miss? what functionality was used?

see below the anchors arround the picture, (not selectable)

It's a powerpoint 365 (or lower) feature not present on 2010 version ?